# spring mvc-data in the database gets updated automatically while manipulating the result

Tags: java, hibernate, spring-mvc

While trying to manipulate the result obtained in an ArrayList using hibernate along with spring mvc, the data in the database changes on its own.

Below is my code.

```
    public ArrayList<SellerDummy> listAllSellers() {
    Session session = this.sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();
    ArrayList<SellerDummy> sellerList = new ArrayList<SellerDummy>(session.createQuery("from SellerDummy").list());
    for(SellerDummy sellerDummy: sellerList){
        String sellerType = sellerDummy.getSellerType();
        SellerType sellerType1= (SellerType) session.get(SellerType.class, Integer.parseInt(sellerType));
        sellerDummy.setSellerType(sellerType1.getSellerType());
    }
    return sellerList;
}
```

Here the DAOImpl class uses the "listAllSellers" method the retrieve the data from the SellerDummy table. SellerDummy table has a column named "SellerType(VARCHAR)" which holds the id of the corresponding SellerType[another table] (e.g 1 = "Manufacturer", 2 = "Wholesaler"). What I'm trying to achieve is use the id of "SellerType" available in the "SellerDummy", make a query to get corresponding String from the "SellerType" and set it in the result obtained from "SellerDummy" table.

To be more precise. For e.g. If I get "1" in the result from "SellerDummy", it should change "1" to "Manufacturer" in the ArrayList(sellerList). The code changes it in the ArrayList as well as database.

Result of sellerList

```
    {"id":1,"organisationName":"Ta","email":"rahul.paryani.2108@gmail.com","password":"MTIxMg==","phoneNumber":"512","address":"12","address2":"12","city":"12","state":"12","pinCode":"12","statusId":"1","sellerType":"Manufacturer"}
```

Logs

```
    Hibernate: select sellerdumm0_.id as id1_0_, sellerdumm0_.address as address2_0_, sellerdumm0_.address2 as address3_0_, sellerdumm0_.city as city4_0_, sellerdumm0_.email as email5_0_, sellerdumm0_.organisationName as organisa6_0_, sellerdumm0_.password as password7_0_, sellerdumm0_.phoneNumber as phoneNum8_0_, sellerdumm0_.pinCode as pinCode9_0_, sellerdumm0_.sellerType as sellerT10_0_, sellerdumm0_.state as state11_0_, sellerdumm0_.statusId as statusI12_0_ from SellerDummy sellerdumm0_
    Hibernate: select sellertype0_.id as id1_1_0_, sellertype0_.sellerType as sellerTy2_1_0_ from SellerType sellertype0_ where sellertype0_.id=?
    Hibernate: update SellerDummy set address=?, address2=?, city=?, email=?, organisationName=?, password=?, phoneNumber=?, pinCode=?, sellerType=?, state=?, statusId=? where id=?
```

I can't understand from where does that update query come from???

Thanks and Regards,
Rahul

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that `sellerDummy` entity is in persistent state and you change it in line `sellerDummy.setSellerType(sellerType1.getSellerType());`. When the entity is in the persistent state and you change it, those changes will be propagated to the DB upon flushing the session.

Comment: Thanks Ivan, Your thought was right. I closed the session explicitly right before making changes and it worked. Now, it doesn't update the database.